# oracle 10g overloaded procedures in a package

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, overloading, procedures

I'm trying to replicate the code found in:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055

I did a copy and paste job. The package audit_pkg and the body compiled fine. But when I added the triggers the debug says "too many declarations for check_val" ...

Everything I've found says 10g supports overloading (or at least doesn't say otherwise).

Thoughts?

Comment: That doesn't happen for me, admittedly on 11G, but I would expect it to work on 10G too.  Are you sure you didn't do something different from Tom's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure declarations in the package specification must match EXACTLY the declarations in the package body. This is where I usually encounter this error.

Comment: I believe that causes a compile-time error on the package body, whereas this is a compile-time error on the trigger referencing the package.

Comment: So I did modify it, to include an entry for char() type columns. Realized it was a causing a conflict with the varchar2() procedure. I wouldn't have expected that, but since the varchar2() procedure is auditing the char() columns I'm ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the column you're trying to use this package with a varchar2, number or date? If it's not, Oracle has to implicitly convert it to one of those three, and it won't know which one to use (and, therefore, which procedure to use). You may need to expand the package to handle more data types.